# How twining the Smyfony's UserAuthenticator with a validation code via email

Tags: symfony

I can't find a tuto on how to authenticate with a code sending by email using Symfony's UserAuthenticator.
So if anyone has any ideas, I'd be glad to hear from you.

So this is the Symfony's UserAuthenticator :

```
class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $authCodeMailer;

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,MyAuthCodeMailer $authCodeMailer)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->authCodeMailer = $authCodeMailer;
    }

     public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        // Fetch the user from the database based on the email provided
        $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
        $user = $userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->leftJoin('u.cfgUserstyle', 'cfgUserstyle')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid credentials.');
        }

        // Check if the user is active
        if (!$user->getActif()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Your account is not active.');
        }

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($email),
        new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
        [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
        ]
    );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('enter_auth_code'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

My question is how to send an email and then check if the code matches before authenticating.